# EJB Singleton WRITE lock not honored when calling self

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, singleton, ejb

I have this EJB deployed to Glassfish 4 (Java EE 7):

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Lock;
import javax.ejb.LockType;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.WRITE) // WRITE is default, but here for emphasis
public class SingletonBean {

    @EJB
    SingletonBean self;

    @Schedule(second="*/3", minute="*", hour="*")
    public void test_automatic_timer() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test_automatic_timer()");
        self.test();
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test()");
    }

}
```

I expected this to deadlock. When the timer calls `test_automatic_timer`, it obtains the WRITE lock. The call to `self.test()` should wait forever for the lock to be released, but in the logs I have:

```
Info:   test_automatic_timer()
Info:   test()
Info:   test_automatic_timer()
Info:   test()
```

Why isn't this working the way I expected?

p.s. This isn't entirely academic. I want to do a `self` call so that I can get [a new container-managed transaction](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/jpa-and-cmt-why-catching-persistence-exception-is-not-enough.html), but I want to make sure I understand the synchronization better first.

---

### Confirming Steve's answer

Steve's answer is correct. To confirm this, I logged the thread ID and saw that they are the same. I also wanted to confirm that the lock was working, so I rewrote the method bodies as follows:

```
@Schedule(second="*/3", minute="*", hour="*")
public void test_automatic_timer() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("test_automatic_timer()");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
    self.test();
    Thread.sleep(10_000);
}

@Asynchronous
public void test() {
    System.out.println("test()");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
}
```

If this works as expected, the asynchronous call to `test` will be blocked for ten seconds until `test_automatic_timer` is finished. If it doesn't work, `test` will be executed immediately. The logs show:

```
Info:   test_automatic_timer()
Info:   Thread[__ejb-thread-pool11,5,main]
// 10 second pause...
Info:   test()
Info:   Thread[__ejb-thread-pool12,5,main]
```

So it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not deadlocking because the call to `test()` is being made in the same (timer execution) thread.

That said I think that at least some of the behaviour when self injecting a a singleton like this may be undefined. What will happen if you introduce an `@PostConstruct` method that references `self`?

Your bean name is a misnomer because `@Singleton` beans are stateful.

Anyway, it is probably safer to do something like:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.WRITE) // WRITE is default, but here for emphasis
public class SingletonBean {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Schedule(second="*/3", minute="*", hour="*")
    public void test_automatic_timer() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test_automatic_timer()");
        sessionContext.getBusinessObject(StatelessSessionBean.class).test();
    }

    @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test()");
    }

}
```

And this is indeed the way to self invoke an EJB with a new transaction.

Comment: I confirmed that your answer is correct and updated my question. Thanks for your help.